# why i cant return the value i pass in function parameter PL SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Okey i was trying to make a fucntion that returns the double of the number passed in parameter
this the function i created

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION fn_double(a number)
return number
IS
begin 
a:=a*2;
return a;
END;
/
```

there was an error "Warning: Function created with compilation errors."
i fixed the error when i changed the function like this :

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION fn_double(a number)
return number
IS
nbr number;
begin 
nbr:=a;
nbr:=nbr*2;
return nbr;
END;
/
```

it works now but I dont know why its working I mean I just tried to change it like this and it worked so  I tried to search in google why I can return the number I pass in parameter but I couldn't  find the answer so Im posting this here just for my personal knowledge why I the first function is not working whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an OUT parameter on a function. You just **cannot alter the value** of an IN parameter. That holds not only for functions but also for procedures.  
Your last function is correct and will return double the parameter. But it can be shortened. You do not need to assign an IN to a local variable before doing operation with it. You can operate directly, just not a LVALUE. Your function can be reduced to:

```
create or replace 
function fn_double(a number)
  return number
is
begin 
  return 2*a;
end fn_double;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [PLSQL language reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#GUID-518B8827-26CC-4734-B799-ACB038185638__PLSQLSUBPROGRAMPARAMETERMODES-521E28A5), *subprogram cannot change this [meant "of parameter of mode IN"] value*.

Comment: oh I get it I thought we use out mode only in procedure because its the only way to return the value , I didn't know we need out mode in function if I want to return the variable passed in parameter ,it makes so much sense now thank you